# How to execute multiple tasks in parallel in fabric

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I know that by using `-P` switch or `@parallel` tag I can run task in parallel on multiple hosts.

I'm trying to execute multiple long running tasks in parallel on the same host:

```
@task
def task1():
  # long running op

@task
def task2():
  #long running op

@task
def task3():
  #long running op

@task
def backup_all():
  execute(task1)
  execute(task2)
  execute(task3)
```

How can I start task1, task2 and task3 in parallel on the same host by using fabric.
I know that I can run multiple fab processes with different tasks, but I'm looking for a solution that involves fabric.

Comment: You could try using `threading` or `multiprocessing`. I haven't used it before, but thought it as a fun [exercise](https://github.com/quapka/expecto-anything/tree/master/multiproc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of ways to address this task. You could use bash/linux level job controls and run the tasks in the background with `bg` and then `wait` for them to complete. [Documentation explaining this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) style of control mechanism.

If you still really wanted to use Fabric/Python for this, you'd likely need to use the `job_queue` that's already in the lib and sorta write your own queue to push these into, or [read up on multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and just do some simple python forking. Though that is essentially all the `job_queue` is doing.

Comment: As there is no "right" answer because Fabric doesn't support this I will pick this answer. It's the closest to the solution I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`fabric` runs one task per host. [`-P` switch just runs task in parallel on *different* hosts](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/parallel.html). No parallelization on the same host.

You could parallelize commands manually e.g., using `xargs -P` or [GNU `parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#gnu_parallel_tutorial).

[`Invoke` (beta)](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/) claims the ability to run tasks in parallel. It extracts non-ssh parts from `fabric`. If it is installed on remote hosts then you could use fabric to invoke `invoke` command that would run tasks in parallel on the same host.